# Cannot find mvn while its installed

Tags: java, maven

does anyone knwos how to fix this error. I downloaded mvn and installed it but got this error.

**mvn not found**

```
M2_HOME=/Users/claudia/apache-maven-3.6.3/apache-maven/src
M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have installed the binaries of maven, if so `M2_HOME`must be:

```
M2_HOME=/Users/claudia/apache-maven-3.6.3/
```

in this directory should be a bin directory which contains the mvn files

Comment: @dsp Do you found the `bin` directory inside of the `apache-maven-3.6.3` directory?